# Should Keras with Theano backend be over 18X slower than with Tensorflow backend?

Tags: tensorflow, theano, keras

I've just installed keras, tensorflow and theano on my machine and did a quick comparison of keras using tensorflow as a backend to using theano as a backend. The results were more extreme than I expected.

I am using the following versions of the 3 packages:

```
>>> theano.__version__
'0.8.2'
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'0.12.1'
>>> keras.__version__
'1.2.1'
```

To compare the two backends, I used the `cifar10_cnn.py` When I use tensorflow as my backend, I get this result:

```
deep@deep-Precision-7710:~/Downloads/keras/examples$ python cifar10_cnn.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
X_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
50000 train samples
10000 test samples
Using real-time data augmentation.
Epoch 1/200
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least   one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Quadro M5000M
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0505
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.93GiB
Free memory: 7.59GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M5000M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
50000/50000 [==============================] - 16s - loss: 1.7916 - acc:    0.3350 - val_loss: 1.4998 - val_acc: 0.4490
Epoch 2/200
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s - loss: 1.4020 - acc: 0.4907 - val_loss: 1.2039 - val_acc: 0.5779
Epoch 3/200
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s - loss: 1.2460 - acc: 0.5531 - val_loss: 1.0272 - val_acc: 0.6311
```

and the whole thing takes just over `51 mins` to run.

When I use Theano as my backend, I get this result:

```
deep@deep-Precision-7710:~/Downloads/keras/examples$ python cifar10_cnn.py 
Using Theano backend.
X_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
50000 train samples
10000 test samples
Using real-time data augmentation.
Epoch 1/200
50000/50000 [==============================] - 292s - loss: 1.8008 - acc: 0.3286 - val_loss: 1.4991 - val_acc: 0.4613
Epoch 2/200
50000/50000 [==============================] - 285s - loss: 1.4302 - acc: 0.4774 - val_loss: 1.1840 - val_acc: 0.5737
Epoch 3/200
50000/50000 [==============================] - 288s - loss: 1.2690 - acc: 0.5452 - val_loss: 1.0930 - val_acc: 0.6030
```

This takes about 15.75 hours to run !?

Should I be surprised that the keras theano backend is about ***18X - 19X*** slower than the keras tensorflow backend? (I'm including the version of cifar10_cnn.py that I was using) IN convering from one backend to the other, I just changed the backend specification in keras.json. I didn't adjust the image_dim_ordering, since that seemed to be specified by the dataset.

```
'''Train a simple deep CNN on the CIFAR10 small images dataset.

GPU run command with Theano backend (with TensorFlow, the GPU is automatically used):
    THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python cifar10_cnn.py

It gets down to 0.65 test logloss in 25 epochs, and down to 0.55 after 50 epochs.
(it's still underfitting at that point, though).
'''

from __future__ import print_function
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils

import datetime

batch_size = 32
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 200
data_augmentation = True

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
# The CIFAR10 images are RGB.
img_channels = 3

# The data, shuffled and split between train and test sets:
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices.
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                        input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

if not data_augmentation:
    print('Not using data augmentation.')
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
              shuffle=True)
else:
    print('Using real-time data augmentation.')
    # This will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation:
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images

    # Compute quantities required for featurewise normalization
    # (std, mean, and principal components if ZCA whitening is applied).
    datagen.fit(X_train)

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow().
    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train,
                                     batch_size=batch_size),
                        samples_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0],
                        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
    stop = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("\nTime to run:",stop-start)
```

Comment: Doesnt look like theano is finding your gpu, you should get a message of this form `Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX TITAN X`

Comment: @y300 Thanks, that was the issue. The Theano backend now runs at 38 sec per epoch, which is only little more than 2X as slow. I'm still curious about the difference, but at least the world make sense again.

Comment: It could happen I think, depending on your GPU. Also make sure you have cuDNN installed and detected.

Comment: @y300 cuDNN is installed and detected (though its cuDNN 5110, which is slightly ahead of the supported version. My GPU is a Quadro M5500M. Is there any reason to think Tensorflow would work better with this GPU than Theano?